# Regex Remove Spaces

Tags: php, regex

i am trying to strip out space from a simple string but seem to be stuck with the regex.

The string is as follow:

```
$string = '"4 " <sup>5</sup> "6 "<sup>7</sup>';
```

The problem i have here is that I am trying to strip out the space in the "4 " and "6 ".

The code I have to try and do this is as follows:

```
if (preg_match('/.*?[a-zA-Z0-9](\s+)/is', $string, $matches))
{
    $string = str_replace(' ','', $matches[0]);
}
```

Not having luck so far though.. Any idea or am i over complicating things?

Thanks

Comment: What exactly is the rule for which spaces to remove and which spaces to leave intact? Is it "a space after an alphanumeric character"? Or "a space before a closing quote character"? Or something else?

Comment: The space before the closing quote needs to be removed.

Answer (score 2):

From my understanding, you're trying to remove whitespace before the closing quote.

```
$string = '"4 " <sup>5</sup> "6 "<sup>7</sup>';
print preg_replace('/"([^\s"]+)\s*"/', '"$1"', $string);
# "4" <sup>5</sup> "6"<sup>7</sup>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to replace every white space in a string, why worry about a regex? Why not just replace every space in the string?

```
$newString=str_replace(" ","",$yourString);
```

It seems the most straightforward approach to get what you ask for in the question?

Comment: Unfortunately doing this wont be ideal.  The provided string was an example.  If I had paragraph with the exact same string, it would remove every single space.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this?

```
$new = preg_match('/"([0-9])\s+"/is', '"$1"', $string);
```

This matches to "`number` `spaces`" and keeps only the "`number`" part.

Comment: A bit of explanation would be nice.